# jsx-a11y/no-static-element-interactions: how to make span clickable

Tags: reactjs, eslint

In my project we have this lines of codes:

```
    <span
      onClick={this.toggleEditing}
    >
      {this.state.value}
    </span>
```

Needless to say, it produces an error in eslint with message "Visible, non-interactive elements should not have mouse or keyboard event listeners jsx-a11y/no-static-element-interactions". But I don't know what is the best way to fix this situation, should we change it to button and change style to look  like a span. I really don't have much experience with this problem.

Answer (score 5):

Look at the documentation it beautifully tells you what to do.
https://github.com/evcohen/eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y/blob/master/docs/rules/no-static-element-interactions.md#how-do-i-resolve-this-error

For your case, the resolution is to add `role="button"`

```
<span onClick={this.toggleEditing} role="button">
  {this.state.value}
</span>
```

Comment: After adding role="button" the new error is: Elements with the 'button' interactive role must be focusable.
(my code is the same as your solution)

Answer (score 4):

I fixed it using this:

```
<span
    role="button"
    tabIndex={0}
    title="Some title"
    onClick={this.toggleEditing}
    onKeyPress={this.toggleEditing}
>
  {this.state.value}
</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

What is the error? onClick translates to an event in the DOM which is valid (click on a span) so you should be able to make this work.

Comment: Sorry, my question is not clear enough. I mean error in eslint, it say "Visible, non-interactive elements should not have mouse or keyboard event listeners: jsx-a11y/no-static-element-interactions"

Comment: Ah, that's basically an opinion based on semantic reasoning - the idea being that HTML in a page should be intuitive to someone reading it without rendering. A button or an anchor link are obviously meant to be interactive, whereas a division element like a span is not.

Personally I find buttons to be happier inside a form. So I would use an anchor link. It also has the advantage of being an inline element like a span out of the box. 

But yes, short answer: you will have to change the element tag to something intuitively associated with user interaction to eliminate that warning.